# $x^k=1$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of the order of $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $x$ has finite order $n$. Show that $x^k=1$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $n$.

Intuitively, I think I understand this, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $x^k=x^n=1$, then $x^{\gcd(k,n)}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

One direction ($\Leftarrow$) should be easy.

For the other direction here's a hint:
Use the division algorithm to write $k =nq+r$ where $0\le r<n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=nm+r$ where $m$ is a nonnegative integer and $r\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Since $x^k=1$, or $x^{nm+r}=1$, and $x^n=1$ by the definition of $n$, you have $(x^{n})^m=1$, so $x^k=x^r=1$, but this is clearly impossible for $r\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$. Hence $r=0$, done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\langle x \rangle=\{m\in\mathbb{N}:x^{m}=1\}$, Then the order of $x$, is the smallest element of this set, say $n$, which exists by the well ordering principle as the given set is non-empty.Now if $x^k=1$, and $k=nq+r$ for some $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq r\leq n-1$. Then $x^{nq+r}=1$ whch implies $x^r=1$. Thus $r\in \langle x \rangle$, but $r<n$, which is contradicting our assumption that $n$ is the order of $x$.